# Поиск класса по его части его имени Java

Tags: java

Интересна функция, которая по первым трём буквам или символам возвращает список(5 штук) классов, которые на это начинаются. 
Ну т.е. примерно так:

```
String[] poisk(String a) { //Наша функция
    String[] result = new String[5]; //готовим массив для результатов

    // Как-то получаю данные значения. А как - непонятно. 

    return result;//возвращаю их
}
```

Comment: На этот вопрос уже был ответ в английской StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519626, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176527.

Comment: @Arhad, если вам не лень, то было бы хорошо, если б вы хотя бы кратко перевели бы содержимое ссылки в ответе)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылаясь на источник [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519626/how-to-get-all-classes-names-in-a-package) + небольшое изменение, то один из вариантов можно сделать так (ищет все классы в указанном пакадже):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ClassFinder {

    private static final char PKG_SEPARATOR = '.';

    private static final char DIR_SEPARATOR = '/';

    private static final String CLASS_FILE_SUFFIX = ".class";

    private static final String BAD_PACKAGE_ERROR = "Unable to get resources from path '%s'. Are you sure the package '%s' exists?";

    public static List<Class<?>> find(String scannedPackage, String beginStr) throws URISyntaxException {
        String scannedPath = scannedPackage.replace(PKG_SEPARATOR, DIR_SEPARATOR);
        URL scannedUrl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(scannedPath);
        if (scannedUrl == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(BAD_PACKAGE_ERROR, scannedPath, scannedPackage));
        }

        File scannedDir = new File(scannedUrl.toURI());

        List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
        for (File file : scannedDir.listFiles()) {
            classes.addAll(find(file, scannedPackage, beginStr));
        }
        return classes;
    }

    private static List<Class<?>> find(File file, String scannedPackage, String beginStr) {
        List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
        String resource = scannedPackage + PKG_SEPARATOR + file.getName();
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            for (File child : file.listFiles()) {
                classes.addAll(find(child, resource, beginStr));
            }
        } else if (resource.endsWith(CLASS_FILE_SUFFIX)) {
            int endIndex = resource.length() - CLASS_FILE_SUFFIX.length();
            String className = resource.substring(0, endIndex);
            try {
                Class foundedClass = Class.forName(className);
                String[] bits = foundedClass.getName().split("\\.");
                String lastOne = bits[bits.length-1];

                 if (lastOne.toLowerCase().substring(0, beginStr.length()).equals(beginStr.toLowerCase()))
                    classes.add(foundedClass);

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignore) {
            }
        }
        return classes;
    }
}
```

и psvm:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception  {
   // пример поиска ClassFinder.find("com.myproject.java", "Hello");
   List<Class<?>> classes = ClassFinder.find("Название пакета с полным путем", "Первые буквы класса"); 

   for (Class item : classes) {
       System.out.println(item.getName());
   }
}
```

---

Другой вариант (тоже ищет все классы в указанном пакадже):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ClassFinder2 {

    public static List<Class> find(String pkgname, String beginStr) {
        List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();

        File directory = null;
        String relPath = pkgname.replace('.', '/');

        URL resource = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(relPath);

        if (resource == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No resource for " + relPath);
        }

        try {
            directory = new File(resource.toURI());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(pkgname + " (" + resource + ") does not appear to be a valid URL / URI.  Strange, since we got it from the system...", e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            directory = null;
        }

        if (directory != null && directory.exists()) {
            // Get the list of the files contained in the package
            String[] files = directory.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                // we are only interested in .class files
                if (files[i].endsWith(".class")) {
                    // removes the .class extension
                    String className = files[i].substring(0, files[i].length() - 6);

                    if (className.toLowerCase().substring(0, beginStr.length()).equals(beginStr.toLowerCase())) {
                        String fullClassName = pkgname + '.' + className;
                        try {
                            classes.add(Class.forName(fullClassName));
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("ClassNotFoundException loading " + fullClassName);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return classes;
    }
}
```

psvm:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception  {
    // пример поиска ClassFinder.find("com.myproject.java", "Hello");
    List<Class> classes = ClassFinder2.find("Название пакета с полным путем", "Первые буквы класса");

    for (Class item : classes) {
        System.out.println(item.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: А в каком формате надо вводить название пакета? Пакейдж у меня находится по адресу C:\Users\u\IdeaProjects\sorti, в составе есть классы odin dva tri chetire и так далее.        
           
                List<Class> classes = ClassFinder2.find("C:\\Users\\u\\IdeaProjects\\sorti", "odi");

Выдает ошибку Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No resource for C:\Users\u\IdeaProjects\sorti
Не находит видимо? Или ему надо прям папку с классами показать, допустим так C:\\Users\\u\\IdeaProjects\\sorti\\src\\com.company

Comment: @Dmitrii ну тут не по пути жесткого диска же.`com.company` - вот пакет с путем до него...так и надо вводить: com.company

Comment: @Dmitrii я даже специально в `psvm` прописал пример как писать же

Comment: Не уловил что это полный путь) Спасибо, а в каком порядке оно выводит? алфавитно или хронологически?

Comment: @Dmitrii что первое попалось так и идет) сверху вниз

Comment: А что добавить чтобы оно шло по времени последнего изменения? Или по алфавиту?